# I cannot connect to (specifically) google.com with any app using cellular data

Tags: iphone, ios, network, cellular-data, google

All other websites work and can be quickly accessed, even youtube.com will load. google.com will simply not load at all when I try to connect to it over cellular data. It does work over Wi-Fi, however. I tried using a different browser, the Google app, restarting the iPhone, everything. Funny thing though, the Google feed loads in the Google app, yet I cannot search with google within the app.

Comment: Who's your ISP?

Comment: I’m using cellular, but yeah it’s T-Mobile.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it may be an issue with your mobile service provider's DNS. I would try to Reset Network Settings to see if that clears out the cached DNS results.

To reset network settings:
Tap SettingsGeneral > Reset > Reset Network Settings

Comment: This should work but it somehow doesn’t. I’m running iOS 11.2 on an iPhone X model A1865. I have to use bing while on the car lol

Comment: that is crazy, considering you're on new hardware / software maybe it's a bug with a newer release. Did it happen immediately after an update? I'm thinking it has something to do with DNS not clearing or with the DNS of your provider in your region.

Comment: I don't know if this is specifically the issue, but after I uninstalled the T-Mobile app, reset the network settings, then rebooted, Google started working. I was confused because I tried the SIM card on someone else's phone (A1865) and it worked for them. However, this is still a really weird bug considering it's literally T-Mobile's phone app.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to my wife, and after trying a lot of things it looked like it was something to do with location services.

I went into settings, privacy, location, turned off location services, then turned it back on.